# Match Zipcode Database to Address

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, geocode

I have a spreadsheet full of physical US addresses that include zip codes.

I also a database of the estimated lat/long of all zipcodes in the US which can be found here:  http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/

I am looking for a VBA Solution to match the zip codes to the correct lat/long.

A statement that says "If zip codes match, enter the corresponding zipcode in new column".

Comment: How come a VBA solution? If you have downloaded that .csv, you can do a formula (such as Index/Match) to return the GPS coordinates in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I am open to any solution, just figured VBA was the easiest.   Is there anyway you could walk me through the Index/Match process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without VBA pretty simply.  I assume you downloaded that .CSV with the zip codes/GPS coordinates.

In your existing spreadsheet with the Physical Addresses, copy/move the "zipcode" worksheet (open in Excel) to your existing sheet. Then, just use:

`=IF($B2<>"",INDEX(zipcode!$D:$D,MATCH($B2,zipcode!$A:$A,0)),"")` for Latitude, and `=IF($B2<>"",INDEX(zipcode!$E:$E,MATCH($B2,zipcode!$A:$A,0)),"")` for Longitude.

Note that I am assuming your Zip Code will be in column B...adjust the `$B2` as needed.

Index/Match (which is similar to VLookup) works by returning some value from an Index.  The `zipcode!$D:$D` is the list of Latitudes.  The `Match()` part will tell the `Index()` part what Row to use.  You're using the value in cell `B2` and looking for it's match in the range `zipcode!$A:$A`, or the column of Zip Codes.  When it finds a match, it returns the row number to the `Index()` formula...does that make some sense?

Edit: Here's a screenshot of how to use these.  Since they're just formulas, you'll enter directly on your spreadsheet.

[image]

So, in your spreadsheet that you want to add the latitude and longitude to, add the formulas.  Also make sure you've copied the `zipcode.csv` file into your workbook.

Comment: I appreciate your help @BruceWayne.  I am going to try this this afternoon.  I will post the results

Comment: Let me know how it works! Also, big thanks for your question because I can use that zip code database in something I've been working on!

Comment: any chance you can rewrite the formula with the following info just so I can clarify I am doing correctly.   - In my database, the zipcode is in column M.  In the zipcode long/lat database, the zipcode is in column B and the Long/Lat are in columns J and K.

Comment: Please disregard, I just read the bottom part in greater detail.  That makes perfect sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @simpresands - Index/Match is a great formula to learn...for further clarification, check [this site](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) and also [this site](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/)...and of course there's always [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=index+match+excel).  If this works, do you mind marking as the answer?

Comment: Will do.  I probably will not get a chance to work on it until this evening.  Again, I appreciate the help and will make sure to mark answered once I get a chance to work on it.

Comment: should I be writing this function in a module?  A blank VBA code?  Not sure where to enter in excel.

Comment: This is a formula, so will go directly into your spreadsheet.  If your sheet with Physical addresses (i.e. NOT the one downloaded from that site) has a column for latitudes, put the formula for latitudes in that column.  I'll update my post with a picture, so you can see what I mean.

Comment: This has been incredibly helpful.  I am looking forward to solving the problem after work.  Again, thanks!

Comment: I would like to ask a separate question related to this project that I feel you could ask relatively quickly.  Can I ask on this thread or should I start a new one?  Please let me know if you are interested in helping.  Thanks in advance

Comment: For the zip code column, some of them have a more than 5 digit zip code so it does not register as a match.  I would like to remove all numbers and (-) after the first five if they are present.

Comment: If I understand, some of the zip codes include the extra four digits (i.e. `10012-4360`, and you just need `10012`?  Just add this to the `Match()` part: `Index(zipcode!$D:$D,match(left($B2,5),zipcode!$A:$A,0))`  ...you're just adding a `Left([zip code cell],5)` to the formula.  Does that make sense?